# Why would he say "We don't want to support MVC3"?

Tags: c#, web-development, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I work in a small shop at a fairly big company doing intranet web applications. By small, I mean there is 1 other guy in my position... and he graduated with me last December. (we aren't the only IT, but the only ones in our field)

We are switching out an old COBOL system and converting it's only used application suite to a Web App. My company has contracted to a Web Application firm to help with this process who has chosen ASP.NET MVC, during one of the important meetings I asked if they will be using MVC2 or MVC3. Their lead developer said:

> "MVC2, we don't want to support MVC3. haha"

My question is, why is this?

This was several months ago and I've been doing extensive and self training gearing up for the MVC switch. From everything I am understanding, MVC3 is just like MVC2 if you don't use Razor and it fixes a number of smaller bugs that MVC2 had. So in my eyes, I can't see any reason to **NOT** use MCV3.

There has to be something I'm missing. Since I don't really have any mentors to turn to in the real world, I'm coming here. What problems are there with MVC3 that might possibly lead him to say this that I'm missing?

Comment: Most probably, they don't have skills to support MVC3 razor syntax. As you have mentioned, contractors might be willing skip the Razor engine usage, because they do not have enough experience to go with Razor.

Comment: or they just make it a joke, depending how it was said ;)

Comment: The way he said it lead me to believe there might be something wrong with it... or possibly they just haven't trained their people in it yet, like you said. It just makes me feel like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: My guess is, that person may experienced some issue with pre-release versions of MVC3. However, final release with Upgrade tools  is working fine.

Comment: They're waiting to get certification.  "ha ha" WTF is that all about?

Comment: Why don't you just ask him??  How are we to know why??

Comment: Upgrade it to MVC3 yourself with the tool and ignore that developers opinion. He may have had a team to manage that just went through MVC1 to 2 or there may have been resistance from above.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, we had planned on that. It's good to know that it wasn't for any thing wrong with MVC3 itself and just him or his team. That's what I was worried about, it just seemed too good comparatively for him to say something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been using MVC 2 for more than 2 years now, and have application in production from early 2011 which works fine. Currently, we are using MVC 3 in our project without any problems. I compiled some posts that shows why MVC3 would be more productive for your project.

- [MVC 2.0 Vs 3.0 Performance](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50bda637-33f5-4a35-8edc-6e37445ec5d7/mvc-20-vs-30-performance?forum=aspmvc)
- [Introducing ASP.NET MVC 3 (Preview 1)](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1)
- [MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/marcinon/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes)